# matlab deconvolve a square wave from a measured signal

Tags: matlab, deconvolution

I asked this question over on Signal Processing Stack Exchange, not sure if anyone here can help..

I have a signal measured from a radiation detector in a narrow beam of radiation. The peaks I get are quasi-gaussian in shape, see attached picture. [image: Data signal. x axis is in mm, y axis is arbitrary response]

The signal is not a function of time, rather a function of distance. The x-axis is is mm and the y-axis is in arbitrary detector response.

The detector used to measure this signal had a finite width, which is contributing to a broadening of the peaks. What I want to do is deconvolve a square wave of width equal to that of the detector from the signal, hence removing some of the broadening effect.

I am hoping to do this in matlab, however I am having trouble using the deconv function due to each data set being two vectors, x and y, and the fact that each data set is a function of linear distance not time.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: please post the code or a minimum example so we can try something

Comment: I don't think the fact that this is a spatial signal is important. It just means you don't need to worry about causality. If x is linearly spaced then this is effectively a 1D image.

Do you know the [PSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) and [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)? If so then you could perform [Wiener deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) using MATLAB's [deconvwnr](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvwnr.html).

Comment: @jodag thanks for the info! The PSF would be a square wave of width say 0.01mm and height equal to height of the data, SNR I don't particularly know but could play around with various values. Is there a way to apply deconwnr but keeping the spatial information? x is not equally spaced so that could be problematic

Comment: @jodag the width of the PSF is also not the same as the x spacing of the signal

Comment: In attempting the simulate the signal in the figure I realized that the bandwidth of that rectangular filter is going to be pretty wide and it's only having negligible effects on the Gaussians which fall well within the passband of filter. In other words, even if you were to perform successful deconvolution you're resulting plot is going to look almost the same as the current plot.